# Sending emails not working, no errors found in the terminal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email

I'm new on rails, I would appreciate any help. This is the repository of this project: https://github.com/felixpro/Kadra

When a client signup, an email is sent to the mail of the admin to approve that client, otherwise the client will never be able to log in.

I am having problems sending emails, in development and production environment. I have tried everything, but nothing is working for me.

maillers/user_mailer.rb

```
class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer
  default from: 'from@example.com'
  layout 'mailer'

  def new_user_waiting_for_approval(user)
    @user = user
    mail(to: 'pujols.fr@gmail.com', subject: 'New User Awaiting Admin Approval')
  end
end
```

controllers/user_controller.rb

```
def create
  @user = User.new(user_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @user.save
      UserMailer.new_user_waiting_for_approval(@user).deliver_now
      format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @user }
    else
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Could you please add mailer settings from `config/environment/production.rb`? Do you use any service for email sending in prod (Mailchimp, Sendgrid, etc)? Do you know that in dev env emails are not really sent, you can only see them in the server log? If you want to simulate email sending in dev env you have to use letter_opener, mailcatcher or any similar gem

Comment: Hey! thank you for the reply, I already added the mailer settings in production and development mode but now I'm receiving the email output in the terminal in development mode. But in production I have an error `Errno::ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused - connect(2) for "localhost" port 25):`

Comment: If you add your settings to the question I believe we can help you :) Obviously, it shouldn't be `localhost` in prod env

Answer (score -1):

You need to add html page named new_user_waiting_for_approval.html.erb and make sure you have added smtp details in production.rb file

Comment: Hey Gautam Kathrotiya! thank you for the reply, I already added the mailer settings in production and development mode but now I'm receiving the email output in the terminal in development mode. But in production, in heroku I have an error Errno::ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused - connect(2) for "localhost" port 25):